# "Connection closed" When using QNetworkAccessManager and QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I have simple server with **QTcpServer** and simple client with **QNetworkAccessManager**.

1. When I request data from the server via curl or browser everything is ok
2. When I request data from any site via QNetworkAccessManager everything is ok
3. But I can not read data from QTcpServer via QNetworkAccessManager. All requests are reseted. QNetworkAccessManager (client) had send RST (reset connection) right after it received a data from server. And in client code we get the error: "Connection closed" (**RemoteHostClosedError**)
4. Aslo, I tried use QNetworkAccessManager from DownloadManager example and QTcpServer from FortuneServer example in various combinations, but the results were the same.

Tested Qt Versions:

- Mac Qt 5.7
- Linux Qt 5.7
- Linux Qt 5.6.2
- Linux Qt 5.5.1

Wireshark screenshot: [qt-wireshark.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr7rB.png)
The upper parts (with red lines) are results of QNetworkAccessManager, and the latest packets with success result are curl attempt to get data from QTcpServer

Also there is a simple example to reproduce the error: [testNetwork.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Pb09eHyZTfdEpJOHBJc2ktT2c/view?usp=sharing)

And here is sample code for client:

```
void test(quint16 port)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(QString("http://127.0.0.1:%1/").arg(port)));

    manager->connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
                     [](QNetworkReply *reply) {
        qDebug() << QString("Finished. %1. %2").arg(reply->errorString()).arg(reply->error());
        qDebug() << "readed: " << reply->readAll();
    });

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);

    reply->connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, [reply]() {
        qDebug() << QString("readyRead: '%1'").arg(QString(reply->readAll()));
    });
}
```

and for server:

```
QTcpSocket socket;
...
if(socket.waitForReadyRead(5000))
{
    QByteArray request;
    request += socket.readAll();

    QByteArray responce("HELLO, WORLD! HELLO, WORLD! HELLO, WORLD! HELLO, WORLD!");

    socket.write(responce);
    if(!socket.waitForBytesWritten())
    {
        qWarning() << QString("Error occurred in waitForBytesWritten() method of the tcp socket. %1 (%2)")
                      .arg(socket.errorString())
                      .arg(socket.error());
    }
}
else
{
    qWarning() << QString("Error occurred in read method of the tcp socket. %1 (%2)")
                  .arg(socket.errorString())
                  .arg(socket.error());
}
```

Also I created a Bug report on qt.io (QTBUG-56631)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client is making an HTTP request, but your server isn't an http server - it's not sending back a valid HTTP request.

Your client works when you point it at a web server, because that IS an http server.

```
    QByteArray responce("HELLO, WORLD! HELLO, WORLD! HELLO, WORLD! HELLO, WORLD!");
```

isn't a valid HTTP response.

Comment: And I want to thank raven-worx on [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io) for his responce:

Comment: His responce:

At least the response should look like the following.

Note:
each line should end with \r\n
an empty line separates the header- and content-section
Content-Length header is the byte-count of the content

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 12:28:53 GMT
Server: MyServer 1.0.0
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: Closed

XXX